# How to access GPS data from command line on jailbroken iPhone

Tags: ios, command-line, jailbreak, script, gps

Are there any binaries available via the command line to get information  from the GPS on a jail broken iPhone? I've searched through Cydia and haven't found anything, but I wouldn't imagine this would be something brand new that hasn't been developed.

Has anyone come across anything that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

I've come along something very similar a while ago but there was no package needed. I'll try my best to explain how it worked. Firstly, an iTunes backup is required. Next, you will need to access that backup on your computer. There was a program for OS X (and probably for Windows too) that could read these backups. In the backup, there is GPS data that can be accessed but is useless without the other program. It is called [iPhone Tracker.](http://petewarden.github.io/iPhoneTracker/) Also, another option that I have not tried is [this.](http://royvanrijn.com/blog/2011/04/reading-iphone-gps-data-from-backup-with-java/) Other than these two methods, I am not sure of any other methods. Hope this helps!